# How multiply nullsafe float in kotlin?

Tags: casting, floating-point, numbers, kotlin

Consider code example:

```
val contentLength :Long? = 1
val float = contentLength?.toFloat()
val any = (float ?: 0)  * 1.25
//                      ^
//           compilation error here
```

If I try to extract variable herem like that:

```
val casted = (float ?: 0)
```

IDE shows that `casted` has `Any` as type. Why it happens? How to get nullsafe float value from float reference and multiply it to another float value?

**UPDATED**

Replacing `0` with `0.0`:

```
(float ?: 0.0)
```

has no effect. :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Change the line

```
val any = (float ?: 0.0) * 1.25
```

to

```
val any = (float ?: 0.0f) * 1.25f
```

Else you mix `double` and `float` what leads to the compile error